# WPF Scrollview UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add an ScrollBar for my UserControl, I have a left Menu a Top bar and under the top bar is the Content where I put my UserControl so only the content need to have a ScrollBar.

I did this by Wrapping my the Code in my UserControl in `<ScrollView></ScrollView>`
Everything is working fine only not the Full hight not, When I set hight to Auto the content is not scrollable anymore... If I set it to 500px it works but this makes no sense why should I make my content 500px I want that the ScrollBar goes with my Windows size and be always so big like my Window.

It could be so easy microsoft (`<StackPanel Scrollbar="Auto" />`)...
...but why easy...

(Yes I found some Posts here with same problem but no one is resolving my problem)

```
<UserControl x:Class="mausys.telegram"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mausys"
         mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="500">

    <Grid Background="Aqua">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto" >
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
            <TextBox x:Name="telegramtextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="48,78,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="telegramtextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="48,153,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Label x:Name="telegramlabel" Content="Phone Number:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.219,-0.282" Width="106" Height="26"/>
            <Label x:Name="telegramlabel1" Content="Verifycation Code:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="48,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.506,-4.269"/>
            <Button x:Name="telegrambutton" Content="Verify" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.234,0.571"/>
            <Button x:Name="Telegrambutton1" Content="Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Phone_Click"  />
            <Button x:Name="tglogin" Click="tglogin_Click" Content="TG LogIn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Width="120" Margin="277,52,323,928" />
            <Button x:Name="feedy" Click="feedy_Click" Content="feedy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Width="120" Margin="277,13,323,967" />
            <Button x:Name="tbrowser" Content="Open Browser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="BlanchedAlmond" Width="120" Margin="277,86,323,894" />
            <Label x:Name="telegramlabel2" Content="Telegram Account Login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="48,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="343" Margin="48,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215">
                <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="TabItem">
                    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
                </TabItem>
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </TabControl>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="151" Margin="277,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,529,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="126"/>
            <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,660,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="330"/>
        </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

```
<Window x:Class="xyz.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mausys"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:mausys.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="mausys" Height="Auto" Width="1596" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" >

<!--Status and Revisions-->
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="85" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

<Border>
    <DockPanel>
    <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!--Menu Left-->

            <!--Hover effect-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="#23282D" >
                <Label  Foreground="#9EA3A8" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15 0 0 5" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="img/logomausys.png" Width="35" Height="32" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MAUSYS" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Label>
                <Button Background="#23282D" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0" Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Dashboard" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Dashboard" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Background="#23282D"  Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="MLink" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Background="#23282D" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="MLink" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Background="#23282D" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Angellist" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Background="#23282D" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="Anchor" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <!--SEPARATOR-->
                <Separator Background="#9EA3A8" Margin="0 10 0 10 " />

                <Button Background="#23282D" Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="AddressBook" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLinks" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
                <Button Background="#23282D"  Foreground="#F1F1F1" FontSize="14" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" BorderThickness="0"  Height="44" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="CalendarPlusOutline" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>

                <Label  Foreground="#9EA3A8" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5 30 0 5" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="ArrowCircleLeft" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Height="15" Margin="10 0 6 0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="MLink"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <!--APP Content-->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="#F1F1F1" >
                <!--Top Bar-->
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#23282D" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <TextBlock Text="hhh" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#9EA3A8" Margin="6 0 0 0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >

                    </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Height="31" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
                <!--Window Controls & Console -->
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#0073AA" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Button Content="ADD NEW" Width="70" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel  Grid.Column="2" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <Button fa:Awesome.Content="WindowMinimize" Foreground="#0073AA" Background="White" Content="_" Height="31" Width="31" Margin="3" Name="MinimizeButton" Click="MinimizeButton_Click" />
                    <Button fa:Awesome.Content="WindowMaximize" Foreground="#0073AA" Background="White" Content="[]" Height="31" Width="31" Margin="3" Name="MaximizeButton" Click="MaximizeButton_Click" />
                    <Button fa:Awesome.Content="Close" Foreground="#0073AA" Background="White" Content="X" Height="31" Width="31" Margin="3 3 20 3" Name="CloseButton" Click="CloseButton_Click" />
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

            <!--Window Controls & Console -->
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Beige">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <!--local:telegram />-->
                    </StackPanel>

                 </Grid>


            <!--User Controls HERE ARE THE USER CONTROLS-->

            <local:telegram />

        </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Without seeing your layout structure, I assume it's a matter of using `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` as the parent for your `ScrollViewer` where its `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="auto"` by default.

Comment: Whew, ya so your issue just comes down to improper layout structure. Don't need DockPanel, StackPanel will only consume space required by it's children, and should never see hard coded margins like that to create your layout. I would use a proper Grid with rows/columns.

Comment: I did it now like you said here the code: https://pastebin.com/1XvcKTXS and when I set this to Auto no Scrollbar     ``mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="500">``

Comment: Hah no I think you're misunderstanding. If you share a screenshot of what you expect the elements to look like when rendered I'll show you how to make the layout.

Comment: Thank you so much here the screenshot, https://gyazo.com/9455ccf4eadd67c56948a6c72466fb76

Comment: Please put your code into the question, not into some linked coding websites (you can still include the link as an additional information). Regarding your question please note that the sizing of a user control can't be discussed without the context in which it appears. So please add information about the container around your user control. If the container permits unlimited size, then it's no wonder that a user control with auto height wouldn't scroll.

Comment: Your code has the elements all over the place and your screenshot doesn't show even half of them, how do you want this stuff to look in the end?

Comment: I'm currently Baned for Answering, Here the Code from the MainWindow Sorry https://pastebin.com/hmM4Mg4Y

Comment: You should [edit] your question, not answer it. Stackoverflow is not a forum website, so the **Answer** functionality is really only meant for **Answers** and not for **Replys** that belong to the **Question**. If you write Question details as Answers, this might be the reason why you are currently blocked from answering (but I don't really know that)